# Error importing the Node standard library module "crypto"

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, node-modules, cryptojs

When I attempt to compile my app, I get the attached error despite the fact that I am not explicitly attempting to import crypto in any of the files I have written myself.  It seems that it is imported in a file automatically present in the node_modules folder.  Is anyone familiar with the given error?[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF4Or.png)

```
The package at "node_modules\reques\lib\helpers.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "crypto". It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library. Read more at https://docs.expo.io/introduction/faq/#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the request package, it included native Node.js libraries that are not supported in React Native. Use another request library that is made for React native.

Answer (score 0):

This is because a dependency in your react-native project is using the crypto library.

One of the dependencies installed is not made for react-native and is made to run on the server. Find out which dependency that is and you can change it to a react-native compatible library to fix the issue.